# Video source with onclick selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi StackOverflow friends. Sorry for being so noob, but I cannot manage to get this snippet working. All I wanted to do was selecting a number from a , and change the video src of the following player replacing that number inside the url itself. For example if I would choose the number 13 my plan was obtaining a refresh of the player with the new source, in this case "https://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_13_Cartoon.mp4", but as you can see I'm not used to work in js so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance, here's the snippet

```js
function changeVideo() {
        document.getElementById("player").src = "https://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_" + episode + "_Cartoon.mp4";
}
```

```html
<section class="players">
<div class="container">
   <div class="media-container">
      <span class="title">Episode Selector</span>
      <a onclick="{ document.getElementById('episode').value='13'; changeVideo();}">
      <a onclick="{ document.getElementById('episode').value='14'; changeVideo();}">
      <a onclick="{ document.getElementById('episode').value='15'; changeVideo();}">
      <select name="player1-sources" id="player1-sources">
         <option value="">Select source</option>
         <option value="12">12</option>
         <option value="13">13</option>
         <option value="14">14</option>
      </select>
      <video id="player" width="100%" height="100%" controls preload="auto" src="https://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_default_Cartoon.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function changeVideo() {
    document.getElementById("player").src = "https://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_" + document.getElementById('episode').value + "_Cartoon.mp4";
}
```

I hope helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get the select box element
let select = document.getElementById('player1-sources');

// add event listener for 'change'
select.addEventListener('change', changeVideo);

// do this when the select box value changes
function changeVideo() {
  
  // the event listener handler sets 'this' to the element that triggered the handler. So 'this' is our select element.
  
// using the ternary operator here
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

// set the protocol based on number
let protocol = this.value > 10 ? 'https' : 'http';

// set the source
let src = this.value.toLowerCase() === 'film' ? 'https://hostingsite.com/folder/Film_Cartoon.mp4' : protocol + "://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_" + this.value + "_Cartoon.mp4";

// set player source
document.getElementById("player").src = src;

// log it out for fun
console.log(src);
}
```

```html
<section class="players">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="media-container">
      <span class="title">Episode Selector</span>

      <select name="player1-sources" id="player1-sources">
                 <option value="Film">Select source</option>
                 <option value="9">9</option>
                 <option value="10">10</option>
                 <option value="11">11</option>
                 <option value="12">12</option>
                 <option value="13">13</option>
                 <option value="14">14</option>
              </select>
      <video id="player" width="100%" height="100%" controls preload="auto" src="https://hostingsite.com/folder/Episode_default_Cartoon.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer saved me! Sorry for bothering you again, but now I'd like to do something like this: if episode > 10 use https, if less use http, if episode = "Film" go to a particular URL. I tried [this absurd thing](https://hastebin.com/onimunirir.js) but of course it doesn't work. Should I use a switch case? If yes could you let me see how the result should be?